# How to fix libmpfr.so.4 missing?

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I am trying to compile the code below:

```
#include"header.h"
int main()
{
char dateString[20], timeString[20];
struct tm *tmptr;
time_t t;
t = time(NULL);
tmptr = localtime(NULL);
printf("%d ---%s\n",tmptr,tmptr);
return 0;
}
```

Header.h has :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<utime.h>
#include<sys/timeb.h>
```

When compiling this code, I get an error saying that:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Concluding that it is trying to tell me that, the library file is missing, I went through the previous threads and tried updating gcc compiler but I still see this error. Can somebody please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That file is provided by the `libmpfr4` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libmpfr4/filelist), which can be installed by opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmpfr4
```

If it says the package is already installed, you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmpfr4
```